# Cloud Run http to https redirection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, load-balancing, http-redirect, google-cloud-run

On this page it says

> Cloud Run (fully managed) redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS but
> terminates TLS before they reach your web service.

`terminates TLS before they reach the web service` I don't quite understand what it means. The web service means the web application in the container?

I deploy a cloud run, set up a load balancer with serverless NEG.

`http://example.com`returns a `404`.
`https://example.com` returns a `200`.

At which point does the redirection begin? It doesn't redirect automatically.

I only manage to redirect it at the application level.

How does cloud run redirection work?

Comment: The Google Cloud Frontend (GFE) handles HTTP -> HTTPS redirection. The communication from the GFE to your instance is over HTTP (default is port 8080) so that your service does not require SSL configured. The GFE proxies the connections (client <-HTTPS-> GFE <-HTTP-> your_service).

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley Now it makes so much sense!

Comment: Incidentally, I found there is a slight delay when changing the domain where a 404 presents unexpectedly for http traffic and doesn't redirect (and the service is available over https). This resolved after some timespan that I don't recall, maybe an hour. After that http redirects to https as-desired when using cloud run as part of the default feature set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Run has its own load balancer. So, when you call your service you have

```
Sender -----> Cloud Run LB -----> Container instance
```

If you send a HTTP request to Cloud Run LB, you are redirected to a HTTPS.

In your context you use an additional layer: external HTTPS load balancer (also known as GCLB), and you have this chain

```
Sender ------> GCLB -----> Cloud Run LB -----> Container instance
```

You get a 404 in HTTP because GCLB isn't configured to perform redirect. More than that, your GCLB only listen on the 443 port (frontend configuration) and you haven't the port 80 open.

You can update it by following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect). At the end, it's not a Cloud Run issue, only a load balancer issue.

Comment: Thanks for making it easier to understand!

Answer (score 0):

According to document [1] on "Invoking with an HTTPS Request"; the full managed Cloud Run(CR) redirects all HTTP request to HTTPS but terminates TLS before it reaches your web service.

If your service generates a web resources that refers to other web resources with unsecured URLs (http://), your page may be subject to "mixed content warnings or errors [2]".

I tried to reproduce your issue using Quickstart: Build and Deploy [3] but I was unable to, as my URL shows HTTPS.

Does your service generate web resources that refers to other web resources with unsecured URLs?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/https-request

[2] https://web.dev/what-is-mixed-content/

[3] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts#build-and-deploy

Comment: https works fine but it doesn't redirect http to https.

Comment: Is your URL correct? Verfify from **Cloud Console** or by running `gcloud beta run services describe myservice2 | grep hostname` .