# Dbt Docs (http) on Cloud Run (https) - problem

Tags: http, https, google-cloud-run, dbt

I could deploy dbt to cloud run on gcp. But I'm not able to access the service.
Apparently dbt docs uses http, and cloud run uses https... and this is giving me issues...

Edit: the reason was because the service was not exposed and I was not inside the VPC. So if network conditions are good, you will be able to make it work!

Comment: Cloud Run has its own [load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67447280/18265570), which will redirect `http` request to `https` . Are you using any external `load balancer`?  Were you able to 

access the `docs` locally? And you don't want `TLS` to get terminated?

Comment: it runs fine locally, correct, but not in cloud run...
I'd like to access the service (dbt docs, which by default runs on http), by any means, but I'm not being able to...

Comment: Have you tried [this approach](https://github.com/meteatamel/cloudrun-tutorial/blob/master/docs/scheduled-dbt-service-bigquery.md#run-dbt-with-cloud-run)? if this is not worked for you, can you share the minimal reproducible steps that you followed? Are you getting any errors while accessing docs? if yes, share the error as well.  Also, could you confirm about \`load balancer\`?

Comment: the issue was that my gcp tenant did not allow for the service to be exposed externally - after fixing the network issues it worked. So if anyone wants to deploy DBT DOCS on cloud run, go ahead, it works!

Comment: Can you post your solution as answer, so that it will be easier to find for others who are facing same issue.

Comment: @MateusLeão can you post the things that you have fixed as an answer, so that it will be helpful for remaining community members who are facing similar kind of issues to fix them.